# How to make a subtraction between 2 records from the same column using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi Stackoverflow team.

I'm using ruby on rails and i'm trying to find the code to make a subtraction between 2 records from the same column using rails.

I have the following table

```
customers
    id    num_hid     num_oxi
    1        1           2
    2        3           4
    3        5           6
    4        7           8
```

I'm trying to get this result

```
 @result =  last_num_hid_id_4 -  last_num_hid_id_3
 //calcultion is: 7-5 = 2
```

i did this code but this displays the last 2 records in array

```
<% @customers.each.last(2) do |customer|%> %>
  <%= customer.num_hid %>
<% end %>
```

i tried this code but is only showing the last record

```
@last_customer =Customer.all.last
@last.num_hid
```

Can somebody help me with this issue?

I will appreciate all your comments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, but i'm trying to make a subtraction between 2 records from the same column using rails.

Comment: @mechnicov how can i make a subtraction for that array?

Comment: Something like this? `relation = MyRelation.ordered; result = relation.last.my_atr - relation.second_to_last.my_atr`. Please edit the question to make more clear expected output

Comment: Yes like your code

Comment: last - second_last from the same column

Comment: if you see the result that i want is this @result =  last_num_hid_id_4 -  last_num_hid_id_3

Comment: Amazing....thanks for the support. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define class method in your model like this

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.subtraction(atr)
    last[atr] - second_to_last[atr]
  end
end
```

or more efficient

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.subtraction(atr)
    last(2).pluck(atr).reverse.inject(:-)
  end
end
```

And then call it after your model scope

For example

```
Customer.order(id: :desc).subtraction(:id)
# => -1 # if there is continuous sequence of ids
```

Comment: i didn't tried the code but the solution was  @result = Customer.last.num_hid - Customer.second_to_last.num_hid  .

Comment: `Customer.last(2).pluck(:num_hid).reverse.inject(:-)` will prevent extra query